# How to have post count after each listed category

Tags: php, loop

How can I have a post count after each listed category with the following function?
Also, how can I apply this with wp_get_archives and also with the same option as the below function?

```
<ul>
<?php
$args = array(
  'orderby' => 'name',
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'number' => 10, // how many categories

  );
$categories = get_categories($args);
  foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in: %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>&#32;&rsaquo;</li>';
    } 

?>
</ul>
```

Examples:

|(get_categories)

Category item 1 > () 
Category item 2 > ()

(wp_get_archives)

Archive item 1 > () 
Archive item 2 > ()

Comment: for category, you can use `$category->count` as like you have used `$category->name`, and for `wp_get_archives` function use `'show_post_count => true'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For showing category count on your loop -

```
foreach($categories as $category) { 
    echo '<li><a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in: %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a>&#32;&rsaquo; ('. $category->count .')</li>';
    }
```

And for showing count with `wp_get_archives` function, use show_post_count in argument -

```
wp_get_archives( array( 'show_post_count' => true ));
```